# Как найти произведение элементов, находящихся ниже главной диагонали?

Tags: java, массивы

Вопрос в названии. Массив двумерный. Сам массив генерируется рандомно.
Пробовал так, но не получилось:

```java
int[][] array = new int[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        int s = 1;
        s *= array[i][j];
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: что именно не получилось? что вы ждали и что получили, и на каких данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `s` должна жить дольше циклов:

```
int s = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i && j < array[i].length; j++) {
    s = s * array[i][j];
  }
}
System.out.print(s);
```